# How do you create local overrides of HTTP requests in Swift?

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview

In a WKWebView there is a tool called Inspector where it is possible to create "local overrides" which can override the data received. Is there a way to recreate this and read/write to these overrides?

[Local Overrides in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibdPM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tool you are looking for is the `WKUserContentController`.

The userContentController is part of the `WKWebViewConfiguration` that you can provide when creating a `WKWebView`

The advantage that the web inspector has is that it is JavaScript running in the context of the page.  Using the `WKUserContentController` you could inject custom JavaScript onto the page.  From there a JavaScript developer should be able to duplicate the features of the web inspector.

The `userContentController` will also allow you to set content rules for handling restricted content.  You might be able to use some of those rules to define content substitutions.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use it? It doesn't have to be in this regard but I don't have a whole lot of experience with WebKit.

Comment: I can't provide an example, but a quick google search shows many examples on the web.  For example : https://www.capitalone.com/tech/software-engineering/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit/

Comment: Is there a way to do this without JavaScript? I've been looking around and most of the options are too in-depth for me.